# How to preserve the state of an application upon shutdown or power outage?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Let's say I have an application with a lot of activities. Some activities play media (audio or video). On the other hand, assume that the device, which in this case is an Android TV Box, is used in a business environment like a train. The devices have no built-in battery. The boxes stream video from a local server. Passengers are watching a movie or listening to a music track and there is suddenly a (short) power outage. The question is how can I preserve the state of the application so that when the device is rebooted, the latest activity the user was on is started and the media resumes playback from the point it was last playing.
Currently, I think I can get current progress say every 5 seconds and save the playback progress in a SharedPreference like this:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override 
     void run() {
     editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_player_progress), exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
 editor.putString(getString(R.string.saved_video_uri), videoUri.toString());
     editor.commit();  
     }
    }, 5000, 5000);
```

This way I can store video position and URI and then each time I start a player I check the preferences and if there was a stored position with matching uri, I'll resume the playback from that point on.
But, how what to resume my application altogether not just a component (an activity or a player) so that the user starts the app and goes back to the activity he was before?

Comment: "starts the app and goes back to the activity he was before" ... That would require some switch statement to detect and load an "indicator" when the `onStop` of the Activity occurred. Note: RealmDB is more robust than SharedPreferences

Comment: `get current progress say every 5 seconds and save the playback progress in a SharedPreference like `. That is a very bad strategy. You should override the life cyle member functions of your activity and only save for instance in onPause(/.

Comment: @greenapps does `onPause` get called when there is a power failure?

Comment: Power failure? In a train? What do you mean? Every device has a battery. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @greenapps yes, the devices use a DC power. Please see the updated post.

Comment: you will have to store the place where the user left the app same way.

Comment: is power outage that frequent that the app has to frequently save state?

Comment: @ChungLunYuen no but it’s unpredictable